# Start-Job via Invoke-Command: Job is only available in remote session

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to start TShark on different servers via following command:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -ScriptBlock {start-job -ScriptBlock {& 'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe' -b filesize:10000 -b files:5 -w "$tsharkResultDirectory\tshark.pcap"} -Name "TShark"}
```

The command works and everything is fine. But when I connect to the remote server via e.g. remote desktop, and perform the command `Get-Job` nothing is returned.
So that means that the beforehand started job only runs in the remote session. Does anybody know if there is a way to start a job in "global" scope. I don't want that TShark stops tracing if I accidentally close my PowerShell window.

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that the job only exists for the duration of the PowerShell host session, which is why you can't retrieve it when you RDP.

A better approach might be to use the `-AsJob` switch of `Invoke-Command`. You can then retrieve the results by running `Get-Job` on your local machine rather than RDP'ing to the remote host:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -ScriptBlock { & 'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe' -b filesize:10000 -b files:5 -w "$tsharkResultDirectory\tshark.pcap" } -AsJob -Name "TShark"
```

Note again that you'll lose the job if you end your local PowerShell session.

I believe the only other way to run a remote job and have it persist is via the *-ScheduledJob commands as they record their results on disk:

```
PS C:\> get-command *ScheduledJob | Select Name

Name                   
----                   
Disable-ScheduledJob   
Enable-ScheduledJob    
Get-ScheduledJob       
Register-ScheduledJob  
Set-ScheduledJob       
Unregister-ScheduledJob
```